# i want to pick last three days data from my database tables in codeigniter (msql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

i have there tables in my database and i want to pick last three days of data from my 3 different database tables and i also want to show if the data is same then it will show result otherwise show empty rows in codeigniter.

my all there tables look like this ==>

```
id   temp   hum  rain  time
1     16    62    NR   2018-01-05 11:00:23
2     17    62    NR   2018-01-06 11:00:22
3     17    61    NR   2018-01-07 11:00:22
4     16    60    NR   2018-01-08 11:00:23
```

Comment: "i also want to show if the data is same then it will show result otherwise show empty rows in codeignter." This part of your question isn't clear. Can you clarify what you want. Perhaps provide some example data and what the expected output of the query would be?

Comment: if my all 3 tables data is same then it will show result otherwise shows empty row      
accept
my all there tables look like this ==>

id temp hum rain time 1 16 62 NR 2018-01-05 11:00:23 2 17 62 NR 2018-01-06 11:00:22 3 17 61 NR 2018-01-07 11:00:22 4 16 60 NR 2018-01-08 11:00:23

Comment: You have just repeated the same sentence in the question. You'll have to rephrase the question with more detail in a way others with no prior knowledge can understand. You posted the data in an answer. That answer will get deleted. You'll need to edit your question with the data, and you'll also want to format it. Having that data as a sql insert statement would be even better.

Comment: @Goose did you understand my question or still confused ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of the MySQL date and time functions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). The interesting one for this question is `DATEDIFF()` which returns the difference between two dates in days.

It would have been helpful if you'd shown your SQL statement so far, but I'm going to guess that it's something like this:

```
SELECT * from my_table
```

To only select rows with a date within a certain range, `WHERE` is used. In this case, we want only the rows where the time is less than three days from now:

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), my_table.time) < 3
```

You might have to experiment a little to get exactly the result you want, depending on how you want to round off the days.

If you want to get the results within three days *to the second*, you can use the same idea, but with timestamps:

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - 60*60*24*3) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_table.time)
```

60*60*24*3 is the number of seconds in three days.

Comment: But how can i get same data from my all three tables ?

Comment: If all the tables are the same (which begs the question why there are three of them) you can use a `UNION` to combine the results of queries on all three. Since you haven't shown what the relationships are between the tables I can't guess what other choices you have.

Comment: kindly write query for me to easily understand your answer my all three tables have same format but diffrent names.

Comment: It is three of the above select statements, added together with `UNION` - [UNION documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) So it becomes `SELECT bla bla bla UNION SELECT bla bla bla UNION SELECT bla bla bla